# Computation of spin connection

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics, tensors

I want to use to Mathematica to compute compute a tensor, but I don't know how to do it. Actually, I want to compute spin connection which has been discussed in general relativity.

Spin Connection is given by

$$\left(\Omega _{\mu }\right)_b^a\text{ = }
e_a^{\rho } e_{\nu }^b \Gamma _{\mu \rho }^{\nu }-e_a^{\nu } \frac{\partial e_{\nu }^b}{\partial \mu }$$

in which $e^a _\mu$ is the local Lorentz frame field or vierbein (also known as a tetrad) and the $\Gamma^{\sigma}_{ \mu \nu }$  are the Christoffel symbols. The summation convention is used in the equation. 
For example we have

```
e^\rho _a = { {Sqrt[AA[t, r, \[Theta]]], 0, 0},
{0, Sqrt[BB[t, r, \[Theta]]], 0},
{0, 0, Sqrt[CC[t, r, \[Theta]]]} }
```

and $e^b _\nu$ is the inverse of $e^\rho _a$ and $\Gamma$ is

```
{{{Derivative[1, 0, 0][AA][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*AA[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
Derivative[0, 1, 0][AA][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*AA[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
Derivative[0, 0, 1][AA][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*AA[t, r, \[Theta]])}, 
 {Derivative[0, 1, 0][AA][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*AA[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
Derivative[1, 0, 0][BB][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*AA[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
0}, {Derivative[0, 0, 1][AA][t, 
  r, \[Theta]]/(2*AA[t, r, \[Theta]]), 0, 
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][CC][t, 
  r, \[Theta]]/(2*AA[t, r, \[Theta]])}}, {{Derivative[0, 1, 0][AA][
  t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*BB[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
Derivative[1, 0, 0][BB][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*BB[t, r, \[Theta]]), 0}, 
  {Derivative[1, 0, 0][BB][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*BB[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
Derivative[0, 1, 0][BB][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*BB[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
Derivative[0, 0, 1][BB][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*BB[t, r, \[Theta]])}, 
  {0, Derivative[0, 0, 1][BB][t, 
  r, \[Theta]]/(2*
   BB[t, r, \[Theta]]), -(Derivative[0, 1, 0][CC][t, 
    r, \[Theta]]/(2*BB[t, r, \[Theta]]))}}, 
{{Derivative[0, 0, 1][AA][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*CC[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
0, Derivative[1, 0, 0][CC][t, 
  r, \[Theta]]/(2*
   CC[t, r, \[Theta]])}, {0, -(Derivative[0, 0, 1][BB][t, 
    r, \[Theta]]/(2*CC[t, r, \[Theta]])), 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0][CC][t, 
  r, \[Theta]]/(2*CC[t, r, \[Theta]])}, {Derivative[1, 0, 0][CC][
  t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*CC[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
Derivative[0, 1, 0][CC][t, r, \[Theta]]/(2*CC[t, r, \[Theta]]), 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][CC][t, 
  r, \[Theta]]/(2*CC[t, r, \[Theta]])}}}
```

It would be a great honor, if some one could help me.

Comment: You may be interested in the Mathematica package [xAct](http://www.xact.es), in particular the [xTensor](http://www.xact.es/xTensor/index.html) module.

Comment: I don't know any thing about xAct. is it possible for you to give me a tutorial file which computes the spin connection using xAct package?

Comment: I am not the author of the package, and I've never used it before and don't know how to use it.  But there's plenty of information on the website which I'm sure will help you get started.

Comment: @m-goldberg, even after your substatial edit, the OP's first sentence is still filled with typos ;p

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. Have you tried formulating the expression in *Mathematica* at all? You just have to define some matrix functions and do the required derivatives and summations. Where are you stuck? I assume you know what the specific forms of $e$ and $\Gamma$ are, or do you want to leave that open?

Comment: forms of $e$ and $\Gamma$ are given but my problem is in tensor calculation.

Comment: If you could add the given quantities as *Mathematica* code, that would make it easier to provide an answer that is useful to you.

Comment: I have added them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this code meet your requirements?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

n = 3;
coord = {t, r, \[Theta]};

\[Eta] = {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
\[Eta] // MatrixForm;

e = {{Sqrt[AA[t, r, \[Theta]]], 0, 0}, {0, Sqrt[BB[t, r, \[Theta]]], 
    0}, {0, 0, Sqrt[CC[t, r, \[Theta]]]}};
e // MatrixForm
dete = Det[e];
inve = Inverse[e];
inve // MatrixForm
detinve = Det[inve];

"--- Curvatureless Weitzenbock connection (Christoffel symbols) ---";
CurvaturelessConn := CurvaturelessConn = Simplify[Table[Sum[
      (inve[[\[Rho], i]])*(D[e[[i, \[Mu]]], coord[[\[Nu]]] ])
      , {i, 1, n}],
     {\[Rho], 1, n}, {\[Mu], 1, n}, {\[Nu], 1, n}] ];

listcurve := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[CurvaturelessConn[[\[Rho], \[Mu], \[Nu]]], 
    0], {ToString[\[CapitalGamma][(\[Rho] - 1), (\[Mu] - 1), (\[Nu] - 
        1)]], CurvaturelessConn[[\[Rho], \[Mu], \[Nu]]]}] , {\[Rho], 
   1, n}, {\[Mu], 1, n}, {\[Nu], 1, n}]
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listcurve], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]

"--- Computing \[CapitalOmega] ---"
Omega := Omega = Simplify[Table[Sum[
     (e[[\[Rho], a]]*inve[[b, \[Nu]]]*
        CurvaturelessConn[[\[Nu], \[Mu], \[Rho]]]) - 
      e[[\[Nu], a]]*D[inve[[\[Nu], a]], coord[[\[Mu]]]]
     , {\[Rho], 1, n}, {\[Nu], 1, n}]
    , {\[Mu], 1, n}, {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}]]

listOmega := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[Omega[[\[Mu], a, b]], 
    0], {ToString[\[CapitalOmega][\[Mu], a, b]], 
    Omega[[\[Mu], a, b]]}] , {\[Mu], 1, n}, {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}]
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listOmega], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

Comment: I would recommend this tutorial to help you. This is what got me started http://www.physics.ucsb.edu/~gravitybook/math/curvature.nb